# If $x,y\in \mathbb R^n$, then $tx+(1-t)y$ for any $t\in R$ lies on a 'line'. What is line here?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, analytic-geometry

I was reading Generalized MVT. I got stuck in the following concept.

If $x$ and $y$ belong to $ \mathbb R^n$ then it is said that $tx+(1-t)y$ for any $t\in R$ lies on a 'line'. What is line here? How $tx+(1-t)y$ for any $t\in R$  belongs to that line?

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: This is a description of the usual straight line. A line is a collection of points. Let $x,y$ be two fixed points (or vectors). The line joining $x$ and $y$ is the set $$l(x,y)=\{tx+(1-t)y\mid t\in\mathbb R\}$$. If $t$ is restricted to $[0,1]$, then the convex combination of $x$ and $y$ represents the *line segment* joining $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Then how can you tell that the points [tx+(1-t)y] where $t \in [0,1]$ belong to in between $x$ and $y$?@StubbornAtom

Comment: Fix any two points $x$ and $y$ on the number line. Let $z=tx+(1-t)y$ be the line passing through $x$ and $y$ for real $t$. Now if you restrict $t$ from $0$ to $1$, it should be intuitively clear that $\{tx+(1-t)y\mid 0\leqslant t\leqslant 1\}$ represents the set of all those points in the line joining $x$ and $y$ that lies in between $x$ and $y$. This is just the definition of a convex set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x,y\in\mathbb R^n$ be two distinct points (or vectors) in the Euclidean space.

A *line* passing through the points $x$ and $y$ is defined to be the set of points $$ \ell(x,y)=\left\{tx+(1-t)y\mid t\in\mathbb R\right\}$$

If the restriction $0\leqslant t\leqslant 1$ be imposed on $t$, then the point $tx+(1-t)y$ on this line is constrained to lie within the segment joining the points $x$ and $y$. Thus the set

$$\ell'(x,y)=\{tx+(1-t)y\mid 0\leqslant t\leqslant 1\}$$ is defined to be the *line segment* joining the points $x$ and $y$.

Indeed, the line segment is nothing but the set of convex combinations of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Then How can I write this straight line : $2x+3y=1$ in this manner?@StubbornAtom

Comment: May be you have to fix two points on the straight line.@INDIAN

Comment: How you converge two definitions of straight line ? One is from coordinate geometry and another one is from the set theory.@StubbornAtom

Comment: @INDIAN You have given me the *equation* of a straight line. I was talking about the *set of points* representing a straight line.

Comment: @INDIAN Let $\mathbf x=(x_1,x_2)$ and $\mathbf y=(y_1,y_2)$ be any two points on the straight line $2x+3y=1$. 

That is, we have $$2x_1+3x_2=1\qquad\text{ and }\qquad2y_1+3y_2=1$$

I said $\{t\mathbf x+(1-t)\mathbf y:t\in\mathbb R\}$ is the set of all points on the straight line.

Comment: @cmi I recommend going through the [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(geometry)#In_Euclidean_geometry) page.

Answer (score 0):

Write down a parametric equation for the straight line passing through $x$ and $y$, then you will see.

UPDATE

**The line in $\mathbb R^n$ is the set defined in your text, which is an analogy of simple cases $n =2,3$**.

In $\mathbb R^2, \mathbb R^3$, a line is a subset congruent to a 1-dimensional subspace of the whole space. Generally we could also give the same name to such kind of subsets in $\mathbb R^n$.

In $\mathbb R^n$, given two fixed points $x,y$. If $L$ is a subset congruent to $\mathbb R^1$, then for each $z \in L$, $z=y +t(x-y)$ for some $t$, or $z = tx + (1-t)y$. So we *define*
$$
L = \{z \in \mathbb R^n \colon z = tx +(1-t)y \;[t \in \mathbb R]\}
$$
to be the *line* passing through $x,y$.

Since in $\mathbb R^3, \mathbb R^2$, whenever $t \in [0, 1]$, $z = tx+(1-t)y$ lie in the segment determined by $x,y$, and $z$ lies "between" $x,y$, we analogously call $L_{t \in [0,1]}$ the *segment* $[x,y]$.

Comment: what is line here? Why if $t    \in (0,1)$ then $tx+(1-t)y$ belongs to in between $x$ and $y$?@xbh

Comment: Try this for $n =2,3$. For larger $n$, this is an analogy.

Comment: This is not my answer.. I asked what is line here? How $tx+(1-t)y$ belongs to in between $x$ and $y$? when $t \in [0,1]$.@xbh

Comment: @cmi You have asked $t\in\mathbb{R}$, not $t\in[0,1]$

Comment: Then how can you tell that the points $tx+(1-t)y] $ ,$t \in [0,1]$ belong to in between $x$ and $y$?@Bob

Comment: How you converge two definitions of straight line ? One is from coordinate geometry and another one is from the set theory.@xbh

Comment: @cmi If you consider set theory only, then there is no such thing called "line". In set theory you have no operations like $+$ or scalar multiplication.